# How to Set variable in powershell script from c#

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script in Powershell in which I want to set a variable from C# code.

I have the Powershell script in `Install.PS1` file. 
This code is in the `Install.PS1` file

```
$guid = (Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall).Name | 
    % { $path = "Registry::$_"; Get-ItemProperty $path } | 
        Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like $filter } | 
            Select-Object -Property PsChildName
```

I want to set the value for `$filter` from C# code.

Comment: How are you executing the PowerShell code?

Answer (score 0):

This simply does not work.

The nameless first parameter you use with this Cmdlet is the parameter "FilterScript". This Parameter needs a `Scriptblock` as parameter value. There is no C#-Code allowed at this place.

You can find more information about `Where-Object` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-stage variables programmatically with an [`InitialSessionState` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate):

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

// prepare the variables needed
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
iss.Variables.Add(new SessionStateVariableEntry("filter", "*wildcardfi?ter*", "Product name filter value"));

// execute the script
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create(iss))
{
    ps.AddScript("your script goes here");
    foreach (var result in ps.Invoke())
    {
        var childname = result.Properties["PsChildName"].Value;
        // do what you please with childname in here
    }
}
```